# Is it possible to retrieve bitcoins from a Bitcoin address and possibly a private key?

Tags: wallet, private-key

While mucking about with Bitcoin a couple years ago, I setup a Bitcoin address and added a couple bitcoins.

I have the Bitcoin address and possibly a private key, but I cant remember how or where I set it up.
Using blockchain I can see the wallet and its contents.

Is it possible to access the wallet and retrieve the coins?

Comment: Address only? No. Private key? Yes.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a private key, you just need to import it into your client. After that you'll get access to your coins from the old wallet.